# Connect to remote database using SSH tunneling using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, mysql-python, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to remote database using SSH tunneling however I am getting error. I am not sure exactly what is wrong, as when I create ssh tunnel from command line I am able to access the database, however same is not working from python.

command to create ssh tunner, which is working fine.

```
ssh -L 30080:phpmyadmin-www:80 root@host
```

however, following code is not working.

```
def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="pass", db="database"):
    sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('hubif-delphi-dev.qa-egnyte.com', 22),
            ssh_private_key="/home/egnyte/.ssh/id_rsa",
            ssh_username="root",
            remote_bind_address=('host', 80),
            local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 30080)) as server:
        print "successfully connected to ssh"
        con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=password, db=db, host='127.0.0.1', port=server.local_bind_port)
        self.cur = con.cursor()
```

I am getting following error, while trying to create MySQL connection.

```
2017-03-06 10:20:23,509| ERROR   | Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: Connection refused: Connect failed
2017-03-06 10:20:23,509| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 30080) to remote side of the tunnel
---------------------------------------- Stacktrace removed ----------------------------------------
   super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

Comment: local port 30080 is bound in ssh, while connection is attempted on port 3308, is that a typo ?

Comment: @Guillaume yes, there was a typo, I have corrected and updated the question as well.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to mysql...but mysql very rarely runs on port 80.  Are you sure your remote port is correct?